# How to add the drop-down box in Expired products admin grid in Magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created one module that module name is Expiryproducts Manager.

In my requirement Expired products Manager admin grid, How to add one drop down box in selected months. I have select for the particular month that particular months expired products only display.

How to find this problem.I will try but I have not got the perfect solution.

Anyone, can you have any ideas? Can you please help me? The below screenshot is my requirement? https://prnt.sc/hkn41c

---

This is my grid file path:
`app/code/local/Dinesh/Expired products/Block/Adminhtml/Expired products/Grid.php`

```
<?php

class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block_Adminhtml_Expiredproducts_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId("expiredproductsGrid");
            $this->setDefaultSort("entity_id");
            $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }

        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');
            $plusOneMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . "+1 months"));

            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect("name")->addFieldToFilter('expiry_date', array('from' => $currentDate, 'to' => $plusOneMonth));

            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }

        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $this->addColumn("entity_id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("ID"),
                "align" =>"right",
                "width" => "50px",
                "type" => "number",
                "index" => "entity_id",
            ));

            $this->addColumn("name", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Name"),
                "index" => "name",
            ));
            $this->addColumn("sku", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("SKU"),
                "index" => "sku",
            ));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV')); 
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }

        public function getRowUrl($row)
        {
            return '#';
        }

        protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('entity_ids');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(true);
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('remove_expiredproducts', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('expiredproducts')->__('Remove Expiredproducts'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_expiredproducts/massRemove'),
                'confirm' => Mage::helper('expiredproducts')->__('Are you sure?')
            ));
            return $this;
        }

}
```

---

This is path :
`app/etc/modules/Dinesh_Expiredproducts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
  </modules>
</config>
```

---

This is the path:
`app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <expiredproducts>
        <class>Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Helper</class>
      </expiredproducts>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <expiredproducts>
        <class>Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block</class>
      </expiredproducts>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <expiredproducts>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Dinesh_Expiredproducts</module>
          <frontName>admin_expiredproducts</frontName>
        </args>
      </expiredproducts>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <report module="reports">
        <children>
          <products module="reports">
            <children>
              <expiredproducts module="reports">
                <title>Expiredproducts</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>admin_expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts</action>
              </expiredproducts>
            </children>
          </products>
        </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <expiredproducts translate="title" module="expiredproducts">
              <title>Expiredproducts</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <expiredproducts translate="title">
            <title>Manage Expiredproducts</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          </expiredproducts>
              </children>
            </expiredproducts>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <expiredproducts>
          <file>expiredproducts.xml</file>
        </expiredproducts>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

---

This is the path:
`app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Block/Adminhtml/Expiredproducts.php`

```
<?php


class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block_Adminhtml_Expiredproducts extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->_controller = "adminhtml_expiredproducts";
        $this->_blockGroup = "expiredproducts";
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Expiredproducts Manager");
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Add New Item");
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }

}
```

---

This is the controller path:
`app\code\local\Dinesh\Expiredproducts\controllers\Adminhtml\ExpiredproductsController.php`

```
<?php

class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Adminhtml_ExpiredproductsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('expiredproducts/expiredproducts');
        return true;
    }

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("expiredproducts/expiredproducts")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Expiredproducts  Manager"),Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Expiredproducts Manager"));
        return $this;
    }
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->_title($this->__("Expiredproducts"));
        $this->_title($this->__("Manager Expiredproducts"));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Export order grid to CSV format
     */
    public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'expiredproducts.csv';
        $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    } 
    /**
     *  Export order grid to Excel XML format
     */
    public function exportExcelAction()
    {
        $fileName   = 'expiredproducts.xml';
        $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }
}
```

---

This is helper file path:
`app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

---

This is layout path:
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/expiredproducts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <expiredproducts_adminhtml_expiredproducts_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts" name="expiredproducts" />
    </reference>
  </expiredproducts_adminhtml_expiredproducts_index>
</layout>
```

Can you please help me?